# Make MYSQL query more efficient, join group by and having count

Tags: mysql

Using mysql 8.0.28

I have this query and it can be very slow. I was wondering if there was anything that could be done to speed it up?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t2.id AS t2_id, t1.id AS t1_id
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
WHERE t1.activity_status = "AnonymousStatus"
AND (t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType1" OR t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType2")
AND (t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass1" OR t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass2")
GROUP BY t1.tag_id
HAVING COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 1
```

Essentially I want to join table t1 and t2, and get all the records that have a specific status, type and class. As well, I only want the records with the tag_id only having one response.

I added indexed for:
table1.tag_id, table1.activity_status, table1.activity_type, table2.tag_id, table2.item_class, but it isn't using any indexing when I run explain. Is there a way I could rewrite the query to be more efficient or do a different index?

edit:
explain:

```
id    select_type    table    partitions    type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref    rows    filtered    Extra

1     SIMPLE         t1       NULL          ref     index1,index2     index2    32       const  1119    19.00     Using where; Using temporary

1     SIMPLE         t2       NULL          ref     index3,index4     index3    111      t1.column    4      12.98     Using where

t1 = 1565116 rows
t2 = 40135 rows
```

Comment: Please show the results of the explain and let is know how many rows you have in each table.

Comment: @Shadow updated the question

Comment: Your query does use indexes. I can also see that the number of rows is also very low. Not sure mysql would significantly speed up if you had different indexes.

Comment: How slow is _"very slow"_? Please add the DDL and index stats (`SHOW INDEXES FROM tbl_name;`) for both tables. Adding a composite index on `(activity_status, activity_type, tag_id)` (try with and without tag_id) should help. Also adding an index on `(tag_id, item_class)` will likely help. How selective are the t1 and t2 criteria? How many rows are returned in the resultset?

Answer (score 0):

First, cleaned readability of your query to better see relationships, where and/or conditions

```
SELECT 
        t1.*, 
        t2.*, 
        t2.id AS t2_id, 
        t1.id AS t1_id
    FROM 
        table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
                ON t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
    WHERE 
            t1.activity_status = "AnonymousStatus"
        AND (   t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType1" 
            OR  t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType2" )
        AND (   t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass1" 
            OR  t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass2" )
    GROUP BY 
        t1.tag_id
    HAVING 
        COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 1
```

Next, you have a LEFT JOIN to table2, but then have an AND clause that
are explicitly including a test to a T2 column which in-turn makes this
a standard INNER JOIN.

Your tables should have indexes on them to help, specifically including your where clause conditions such as

```
table      index
table1     (tag_id, activity_status, activity_type )
table2     (tag_id, item_class )
```

Finally, your group by SHOULD fail.  A group by should have all non-aggregate columns, but you have no aggregates in the columns being returned, just the count.   Don't know what your table columns have as you are ambiguous in your question, but your group by is the t1.id... so do you want the first t2 ID per t1 ID, or maybe how many t2 entries within each ID.  Having said that, this might be more appropriate.

```
SELECT 
        t1.tag_id,
        min( t1.id ) minT1ID,
        min( t2.id ) minT2ID,
        count( t1.id ) NumT1Entries,
        count( t2.id ) NumT2Entries
    FROM 
        table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
                ON t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
    WHERE 
            t1.activity_status = "AnonymousStatus"
        AND (   t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType1" 
            OR  t1.activity_type = "AnonymousType2" )
        AND (   t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass1" 
            OR  t2.item_class = "AnonymousClass2" )
    GROUP BY 
        t1.tag_id
    HAVING 
        COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 1
```

Clarification and an update to what you are asking for should be done.  Edit your question (not via comments) and please provide more explicit what you are looking for.